# how to iterate over a number to get every other digit

Tags: c

For a homework program we are asked to check if credit card numbers are valid.
While I am fairly sure about how I want to solve this problem I am stuck with iterating over a creditcard number and getting every second digit.

I already know that I need to use modulo and division and I do get the second to last number, but I am lost at how to iterate over the rest of the numbers.
In the code is the code I used to check that I did indeed get the second to last number, and after that some code I tried to use to iterate over the complete number. Hope somebody could show me in the right direction!

```
   long number = 378282246310005;
    int digit;
    int cc_number;
    cc_number = number % 10;
    digit = cc_number / 10;
    printf("%i\n", digit);

while (number > 0)
   {
      digit += number % 10;
      number /= 10;
      printf("%li", number);
   }
   printf("\n");
```

Comment: If you can, it is easier to use string.

Comment: Sorry should have told that we have to use long, and we're also not allowed to use arrays, which would have made things easier I believe.

Comment: If you count the positions in your loop you can use `if (i % 2 == 0) { /* do something with your number */}` to select every second digit. If you want to select the remaining numbers you can test for `1` instead of `1`

Comment: The first printf very likely outputs 0, but that is none of the 0s in the value in the first line. And the following printfs seem meaning-free to me. Please show the output of the shown code and explain it. Otherwise please make an honest attempt of approaching the homework assignment. Otherwise the question is too broad to be answered, as most questions which give the impression of being a homework copy. Credits to your attempt to provide a minimum of code. But the shown code amounts to nothing.

Comment: The next time I suggest to show a minimal complete program that can be compiled and tested. That means wrap your code snippet in a `main` function with all required `#include` directives. This will make it easier to reproduce the problem or to provide an improved version.

Answer (score 4):

Before your `while` loop you reversed the last digit and the remaining number.

`number % 10` is the last digit, `number / 10` is the remaining number.

Adding to `digit` doesn't make sense if the variable is intended to contain a single digit. (You may need to add the digits for a validity check.)

Example code to extract all digits and their positions:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    long number = 378282246310005;
    int digit;
    int position = 0;

    printf("%li\n", number);

    while (number > 0)
    {
        digit = number % 10;
        number /= 10;
        printf("(%i) %i ", position, digit);
        position++;
    }
    printf("\n");

    return 0;
}
```

This prints

```
378282246310005
(0) 5 (1) 0 (2) 0 (3) 0 (4) 1 (5) 3 (6) 6 (7) 4 (8) 2 (9) 2 (10) 8 (11) 2 (12) 8 (13) 7 (14) 3
```

To select every other digit you could check `position % 2` or toggle a variable between 0 and 1 in every loop cycle.

**Edit:**
Explanation as requested in [ron_g](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4916945/ron-g)'s comment: "Why's it printing out the digits in reverse?"

The loop separates the last digit from the remaining part of the number, so it prints the last digit first. Then it repeats the same with the remaining part as long as the remaining number is not 0.

The answer keeps the original implementation from the question which is based on storing the number as a `long int`. In this case it is easier to start with the last digit. When the number would be stored as a string it would be easier to start with the first digit.

```
    /* number is initially the whole number or the remaining part */
    while (number > 0)
    {
        /* remainder of division by 10 is the last digit */
        digit = number % 10;
        /* division by 10 is the remaining part after cutting off the last digit */
        number /= 10;
        printf("(%i) %i ", position, digit);
        position++;
    }
```

Comment: Why's it printing out the digits in reverse?

Comment: @ron_g I added an explanation to the answer.